# How to drag an image and drop it inside a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to drag and drop some images inside my canvas with the size i made them, but it doesn't work.

```js
//Javascript per la creazione di cirucuiti elettrici

const NUMERO_CICLO = 990;
const NUMERO_CICLO_INTERNO = 60;


const resistor = document.getElementById("component_circuit_resistor");
const condensator = document.getElementById("component_circuit_condensator");
const tranistor = document.getElementById("component_circuit_tranistor");
const alimentator = document.getElementById("component_circuit_alimentator");
const circuit = document.getElementById("components_circuit");
const back_button = document.getElementById("back-button");
const clear_button = document.getElementById("clear-button");
const draggable = document.querySelectorAll(".draggable");
const container = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const foward_button = document.getElementById("foward-button");

canvas.width = 1500;
canvas.height = 855;
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
circuit.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.style.borderRadius = "10px";
canvas.style.marginLeft = "auto";
canvas.style.marginRight = "auto";
canvas.style.display = "block";
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


const circles = [];
const lines = [];
const lines_c = [];
var deletedLines = [];

for (let y = 20; y <= NUMERO_CICLO; y += 20) {
  for (let i = 0; i < NUMERO_CICLO_INTERNO; i++) {
    circles.push({
      x: 13 + i * 25,
      y,
      radius: 5,
      color: "grey",
    });
  }
}

let startCircle = null;
let endCircle = null;


function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  circles.forEach((circle) => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = circle.color;
    ctx.fill();
  });
  lines.forEach((line) => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.moveTo(line.start.x, line.start.y);
    ctx.lineTo(line.end.x, line.end.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  });
  if (startCircle && endCircle) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.moveTo(startCircle.x, startCircle.y);
    ctx.lineTo(endCircle.x, endCircle.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
draw();

function goBack() {
  if (lines.length > 0 && back_clicked == true) {
    const eliminato = lines.pop();
    deletedLines.push(eliminato);
  }
  else if(foward_clicked == true && deletedLines.length > 0){
    const lastDeleted = deletedLines[deletedLines.length - 1];
    if (!lines.includes(lastDeleted)) {
      lines.push(lastDeleted);
      deletedLines.pop();
    }
  }
  //se non ci sono linee da eliminare mando alert
  else if (lines.length == 0 && back_clicked == true) {
    alert("There are no lines to delete");
  }
}

function clearCanvas() {
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the circuit?")){
      lines.length = 0;
      deletedLines.length = 0;
      lastDeleted = null;
    }
}

function getNearestCircle(x, y) {
  let nearestCircle = null;
  let nearestDistance = Infinity;
  circles.forEach((circle) => {
    const distance = Math.sqrt((circle.x - x) ** 2 + (circle.y - y) ** 2);
    if (distance < nearestDistance && distance < 30) {
      nearestCircle = circle;
      nearestDistance = distance;
    }
  });
  return nearestCircle;
}

let isDrawing = false;

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", (event) => {
  const x = event.offsetX;
  const y = event.offsetY;
  const circle = getNearestCircle(x, y);
  if (circle) {
    startCircle = circle;
    endCircle = { x, y };
    isDrawing = true;
  }
});

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
  if (isDrawing) {
    endCircle.x = event.offsetX;
    endCircle.y = event.offsetY;
  } else {
    const x = event.offsetX;
    const y = event.offsetY;
    const circle = getNearestCircle(x, y);
    if (circle) {
      circles.forEach((circle) => {
        circle.color = "grey";
      });
      circle.color = "red";
    } else {
      circles.forEach((circle) => {
        circle.color = "grey";
      });
    }
  }
});

canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
    if (isDrawing) {
        const x = endCircle.x;
        const y = endCircle.y;
        const circle = getNearestCircle(x, y);
        if (circle) {
        lines.push({
            start: startCircle,
            end: circle,
        });
        }
        isDrawing = false;
        startCircle = null;
        endCircle = null;
    }
});

//back_button.addEventListener("click", goBack);
//foward_button.addEventListener("click", goBack);
clear_button.addEventListener("click", clearCanvas);
var back_clicked = false;
back_button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  back_clicked = true;
  goBack();
  back_clicked = false;
})

var foward_clicked = false;
foward_button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  foward_clicked = true;
  goBack();
  foward_clicked = false;
})

  //risposta stack overflow
const draggableImages = document.querySelectorAll('img[draggable]');
for (const img of draggableImages)
  img.ondragstart = (ev) => {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData('text', img.src);
  };

canvas.ondragover = (ev) => ev.preventDefault(); // IMPORTANT

canvas.ondrop = (ev) => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text');
  img.onload = () => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  };
};
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');
html,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ede7e1;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    line-height: 1.5;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#h1_disegna{
    text-align: center;
}
#h1_breadboard{
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -550px;
}

#h1_titolo{
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
#h3_componenti_circuit{
    border-style: solid;
    width: 100px;
    border-color: black rigid 1px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-color: sandybrown;
    position: relative;
    top: 85px;
}

#h3_componenti_br{
    border-style: solid;
    width: 100px;
    border-color: black rigid 1px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-color: sandybrown;
    position: relative;
    top: -500px;
}

#h4_footer{
    font-size: 26px;
}


.elementi_disegno{
    position: relative;
    top: -520px;
}

#canvas{
    position: relative;
    top: -520px;
    
}

#back-button{
    position: relative;
    top: 62%;
    left: 42.5%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: rgba(244, 165, 96, 0.473);
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#foward-button{
    position: relative;
    top: 62%;
    left: 43%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: rgba(244, 165, 96, 0.473);
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#clear-button{
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: relative;
    top: 62%;
    left: 44.5%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: rgba(244, 165, 96, 0.473);
    cursor: pointer;
}
#components_circuit_border{
    border-style: solid;
    width: 100px;
    border-color: black rigid 1px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    cursor: move;
    position: relative;
    top: 85px;
}

#components_br_border{
    border-style: solid;
    width: 100px;
    border-color: black rigid 1px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    cursor: move;
    position: relative;
    top: -500px;
}

#components_circuit{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.footer{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: darkgray;
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}

.material-symbols-outlined{
    display: inline-flex;
    vertical-align: -3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>From Circuit to Breadboard</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="h1_titolo">From Circuit to Breadboard</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="components">
            <div id="components_circuit">
                <h3 id ="h3_componenti_circuit">Componenti:</h3>
                    <ul id="components_circuit_border">
                        <li><img id ="component_circuit_resistor" src="images/circuit_resistor.png" height="50" draggable></li>
                        <br><br>
                        <li><img id = "component_circuit_condensator" src="images/circuit_condensator.png" height="50" draggable></li>
                        <br><br>
                        <li><img id="component_circuit_transistor" src="images/circuit_transistor.png" height="50" draggable></li>
                        <br><br>
                        <li><img id="component_circuit_alimentator" src="images/circuit_alimentator.png" height="50" draggable></li>
                        <!-- <li><img
                            src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/006/428/637738.jpg"
                            height="50px"
                            draggable
                          /></li>
                          <li>
                            <img
                              src="https://ftw.usatoday.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/90/2017/05/spongebob.jpg?w=1000&h=600&crop=1"
                              height="50px"
                              draggable
                            />
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <img
                              src="https://pyxis.nymag.com/v1/imgs/0f9/f96/029acbf4c6d8c67e138e1eb06a277204bf-05-patrick.rsquare.w700.jpg"
                              height="50px"
                              draggable
                            />
                          </li> -->
                    </ul>
                <div class = "elementi_disegno">
                    <h1 id ="h1_disegna">Disegna il tuo circuito!</h1>
                <button id="back-button">Indietro
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">undo</span>
                </button>
                <button id="foward-button">Avanti
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">redo</span>
                </button>
                <button id="clear-button">Clear All
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">delete</span>
                </button>
                <canvas id = "canvas" class = "dropzone"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div id="components_br">
                <h1 id = "h1_breadboard">Breadboard</h1>
                <h3 id ="h3_componenti_br">Componenti:</h3>
                <ul id="components_br_border">
                    <li><img id = "component_br_resistor" src="images/br_resistor.png" height="50" draggable="true"></li>
                    <br><br>
                    <li><img id = "component_br_condensator" src="images/br_condensator.png" height="50" draggable="true"></li>
                    <br><br>
                    <li><img id = "component_br_transistor" src="images/br_transistor.png" height="50" draggable="true"></li>
                    <br><br>
                    <li><img id="component_br_alimentator" src="images/br_alimentator.png" height="50" draggable="true"></li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    

    <footer class="footer">
        <div>
          <h4 id ="h4_footer">Website made by Skerdi Velo, Davide Rossini, Andrea Quagliotti<span class="material-symbols-outlined">copyright</span></h4>
        </div>
    </footer>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to drag and drop some images inside my canvas. It lets me drag it but when i want to drop it doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="components">
        <div id="components_circuit">
            <h3 class ="h3_componenti" id ="h3_componenti_circuit">Componenti:</h3>
            <ul id="components_circuit_border">
                <li><img id ="component_circuit_resistor" src="images/circuit_resistor.png" height="50"></li>
                <li><img id = "component_circuit_condensator" src="images/circuit_condensator.png" height="50" draggable="true"></li>
                <li><img id="component_circuit_transistor" src="images/circuit_transistor.png" height="50" draggable="true"></li>
                <li><img id="component_circuit_alimentator" src="images/circuit_alimentator.png" height="50" draggable="true"></li>
            </ul>
            <canvas id = "canvas"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is an example of HTML as you can see I have my images that I want to drop in my canvas. Here is the JavaScript of the canvas:

```
const draggableClass = document.getElementsByClassName("draggable");
const draggable = document.querySelectorAll(".draggable");
const container = document.querySelectorAll(".container");

const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 1500;
canvas.height = 855;
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
canvas.style.borderRadius = "10px";
canvas.style.marginLeft = "auto";
canvas.style.marginRight = "auto";
canvas.style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
//Javascript per la creazione di cirucuiti elettrici

const NUMERO_CICLO = 990;
const NUMERO_CICLO_INTERNO = 60;

const resistor = document.getElementById('component_circuit_resistor');
const condensator = document.getElementById('component_circuit_condensator');
const tranistor = document.getElementById('component_circuit_tranistor');
const alimentator = document.getElementById('component_circuit_alimentator');
const circuit = document.getElementById('components_circuit');
const back_button = document.getElementById('back-button');
const clear_button = document.getElementById('clear-button');
const draggable = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
const container = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const foward_button = document.getElementById('foward-button');

/** EDIT START */
const draggableImages = document.querySelectorAll('img[draggable]');

for (let i = 0; i < draggableImages.length; i++)
  draggableImages[i].ondragstart = (ev) => {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', i.toString());
  };

canvas.ondragover = (ev) => ev.preventDefault(); // IMPORTANT

const drawnImageData = [];

canvas.ondrop = (ev) => {
  const index = parseInt(ev.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
  const img = draggableImages[index];
  drawnImageData.push({ img, x: ev.offsetX, y: ev.offsetY });
};
/** EDIT END */

canvas.width = 1500;
canvas.height = 855;
canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgrey';
circuit.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.style.borderRadius = '10px';
canvas.style.marginLeft = 'auto';
canvas.style.marginRight = 'auto';
canvas.style.display = 'block';
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const circles = [];
const lines = [];
const lines_c = [];
var deletedLines = [];

for (let y = 20; y <= NUMERO_CICLO; y += 20) {
  for (let i = 0; i < NUMERO_CICLO_INTERNO; i++) {
    circles.push({
      x: 13 + i * 25,
      y,
      radius: 5,
      color: 'grey',
    });
  }
}

let startCircle = null;
let endCircle = null;

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  circles.forEach((circle) => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = circle.color;
    ctx.fill();
  });
  lines.forEach((line) => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.moveTo(line.start.x, line.start.y);
    ctx.lineTo(line.end.x, line.end.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  });
  if (startCircle && endCircle) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.moveTo(startCircle.x, startCircle.y);
    ctx.lineTo(endCircle.x, endCircle.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  /** EDIT START */
  for (const data of drawnImageData)
    ctx.drawImage(data.img, data.x, data.y, data.img.width, data.img.height);
  /** EDIT END */
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
draw();

function goBack() {
  if (lines.length > 0 && back_clicked == true) {
    const eliminato = lines.pop();
    deletedLines.push(eliminato);
  } else if (foward_clicked == true && deletedLines.length > 0) {
    const lastDeleted = deletedLines[deletedLines.length - 1];
    if (!lines.includes(lastDeleted)) {
      lines.push(lastDeleted);
      deletedLines.pop();
    }
  }
  //se non ci sono linee da eliminare mando alert
  else if (lines.length == 0 && back_clicked == true) {
    alert('There are no lines to delete');
  }
}

function clearCanvas() {
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the circuit?')) {
    lines.length = 0;
    deletedLines.length = 0;
    lastDeleted = null;
  }
}

function getNearestCircle(x, y) {
  let nearestCircle = null;
  let nearestDistance = Infinity;
  circles.forEach((circle) => {
    const distance = Math.sqrt((circle.x - x) ** 2 + (circle.y - y) ** 2);
    if (distance < nearestDistance && distance < 30) {
      nearestCircle = circle;
      nearestDistance = distance;
    }
  });
  return nearestCircle;
}

let isDrawing = false;

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  const x = event.offsetX;
  const y = event.offsetY;
  const circle = getNearestCircle(x, y);
  if (circle) {
    startCircle = circle;
    endCircle = { x, y };
    isDrawing = true;
  }
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  if (isDrawing) {
    endCircle.x = event.offsetX;
    endCircle.y = event.offsetY;
  } else {
    const x = event.offsetX;
    const y = event.offsetY;
    const circle = getNearestCircle(x, y);
    if (circle) {
      circles.forEach((circle) => {
        circle.color = 'grey';
      });
      circle.color = 'red';
    } else {
      circles.forEach((circle) => {
        circle.color = 'grey';
      });
    }
  }
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  if (isDrawing) {
    const x = endCircle.x;
    const y = endCircle.y;
    const circle = getNearestCircle(x, y);
    if (circle) {
      lines.push({
        start: startCircle,
        end: circle,
      });
    }
    isDrawing = false;
    startCircle = null;
    endCircle = null;
  }
});

//back_button.addEventListener("click", goBack);
//foward_button.addEventListener("click", goBack);
clear_button.addEventListener('click', clearCanvas);
var back_clicked = false;
back_button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  back_clicked = true;
  goBack();
  back_clicked = false;
});

var foward_clicked = false;
foward_button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  foward_clicked = true;
  goBack();
  foward_clicked = false;
});
```

```html
<h1 id="h1_titolo">From Circuit to Breadboard</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="components">
    <div id="components_circuit">
      <h3 id="h3_componenti_circuit">Componenti:</h3>
      <ul id="components_circuit_border">
        <li>
          <img
            id="component_circuit_resistor"
            src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/006/428/637738.jpg"
            height="50"
            draggable
          />
        </li>
        <br /><br />
        <li>
          <img
            id="component_circuit_condensator"
            src="https://ftw.usatoday.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/90/2017/05/spongebob.jpg"
            height="50"
            draggable
          />
        </li>
        <br /><br />
        <li>
          <img
            id="component_circuit_transistor"
            src="https://pyxis.nymag.com/v1/imgs/0f9/f96/029acbf4c6d8c67e138e1eb06a277204bf-05-patrick.rsquare.w700.jpg"
            height="50"
            draggable
          />
        </li>
        <br /><br />
      </ul>
      <div class="elementi_disegno">
        <h1 id="h1_disegna">Disegna il tuo circuito!</h1>
        <button id="back-button">
          Indietro
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined">undo</span>
        </button>
        <button id="foward-button">
          Avanti
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined">redo</span>
        </button>
        <button id="clear-button">
          Clear All
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined">delete</span>
        </button>
        <canvas id="canvas" class="dropzone"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
```

You can load an image into the canvas with [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) which accepts an [`HTMLImageElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement). You can store your draggable images in an array and pass the index of the image when the drag starts.

```
const draggableImages = document.querySelectorAll('img[draggable]');

for (let i = 0; i < draggableImages.length; i++)
  draggableImages[i].ondragstart = (ev) => {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', i.toString());
  };
```

Since you're using animation frames, you'll need to store what images are drawn on the canvas, and where they are. I'm using an array for simplicity, but you might want something else if you're going to allow deletion, re-dragging, resizing etc.

```
const drawnImageData[] = [];
```

Now to trigger the `drop` event on the canvas, you need to prevent the default behaviour of the `ondragover` event.

```js
canvas.ondragover = (ev) => ev.preventDefault();
```

Then get the index of the image when the `ondrop` event fires. Put the image intro `drawnImages` along with the x and y coordinates indicating where to draw. I'm using the position relative to the top left corner of the canvas.

```
canvas.ondrop = (ev) => {
  const index = parseInt(ev.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
  const img = draggableImages[index];
  drawnImageData.push({ img, x: ev.offsetX, y: ev.offsetY });
};
```

Now draw the images in your `draw` function.

```
for (const data of drawnImageData)
    ctx.drawImage(data.img, data.x, data.y, data.img.width, data.img.height);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, I tried your code but works partially, my js draws some circles inside the canvas and when I try to drag and drop doesn't work, if I remove the circles it works but changes the size of the pictures and i can only add one picture. I added the full html/css/js so you can see. Thanks

Comment: @SkerdiVelo I've edited to give you the basic idea.